# where does "create()" method comes from in django

Tags: django, django-models

I just want to know where create method comes from in django.

I checked Model class, BaseManager class and so on.

I cannot find where create method is defined.

Anyone knows about it ?

https://github.com/django/django/blob/2d6179c819010f6a9d00835d5893c4593c0b85a0/django/

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: In the `QuerySet` class.

This is defined in the `QuerySet`. Indeed, in the `Manager`, it is wrapped to the `QuerySet` [source [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/models/manager.py#L81-L101):

> ```
>     @classmethod
>     def _get_queryset_methods(cls, queryset_class):
>         def create_method(name, method):
>             def manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
>                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>             manager_method.__name__ = method.__name__
>             manager_method.__doc__ = method.__doc__
>             return manager_method
>
>         new_methods = {}
>         for name, method in inspect.getmembers(queryset_class, predicate=inspect.isfunction):
>             # Only copy missing methods.
>             if hasattr(cls, name):
>                 continue
>             # Only copy public methods or methods with the attribute `queryset_only=False`.
>             queryset_only = getattr(method, 'queryset_only', None)
>             if queryset_only or (queryset_only is None and name.startswith('_')):
>                 continue
>             # Copy the method onto the manager.
>             new_methods[name] = create_method(name, method)
>         return new_methods
> ```

The `_get_queryset_methods` is called when constructing the [`Manager` class [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/models/manager.py#L168-L169):

> ```
> class Manager(BaseManager.from_queryset(QuerySet)):
>     pass
> ```

and the `from_queryset` will [attach the `QuerySet` methods to the `Manager` class [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/models/manager.py#L103-L110):

> ```
>     @classmethod
>     def from_queryset(cls, queryset_class, class_name=None):
>         if class_name is None:
>             class_name = '%sFrom%s' % (cls.__name__, queryset_class.__name__)
>         return type(class_name, (cls,), {
>             '_queryset_class': queryset_class,
>             **cls._get_queryset_methods(queryset_class),
>         })
> ```

This is done to implement for each method in the `QuerySet` a method in the `Manager` to prevent implementing the same logic *multiple* times. If you thus call `.create` on the `.objects` manager (or any other manager), it will call `.get_queryset()`, and then call that method (here `create`) on the given `QuerySet` that `get_queryset` returns.

The `QuerySet` thus has a method `create` that is [implemented as [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/models/query.py#L440-L448):

> ```
>     def create(self, **kwargs):
>         """
>         Create a new object with the given kwargs, saving it to the database
>         and returning the created object.
>         """
>         obj = self.model(**kwargs)
>         self._for_write = True
>         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
>         return obj
> ```